# How to add Text and Image both in an SWT Label

Tags: java, swt

I heard that `Label` is impossible, but `CLabel` is possible.
 How to use `CLabel` to add text & image?

```
private CLabel label = new CLabel(composite, SWT.CENTER);
label.setBounds(93,35,192, 20); 
label.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("C:\\Users\\Screen.png"));
label.setText(memName + "'s Planet");
```

this is my code. 
but only display text or image....

Answer (score 1):

You could use set setBackgroundImage()

Answer (score 0):

`CLabel` does display the image and the text.

However if there is not enough space for both the image and the text it will leave out the image - so check you have enough space for both.

To display a background image call the `CLabel` `setBackground(image)` method.

Comment: i want to add picture for background.

Comment: You need to be precise in your questions. Added the call for background image to the answer.